# Java JSON Parsing with new BVD API

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm using BVD API to get company informations. The new API response changed from :

```
[
    {
    "companyName": "LE PRINT",
    "bvdIdNumber": "FR834745630",
    "addressLineOne": "2 ALLEE DU PETIT MANOIR",
    "postalCode": "14100",
    "city": "ST MARTIN DE LA LIEUE",
    "country": "France"
    }
]
```

To:

```
"SearchSummary": {
    "TotalRecordsFound": 1,
    "Offset": 0,
    "RecordsReturned": 1,
    "DatabaseInfo": {
        "ReleaseNumber": "338",
        "UpdateNumber": "338001",
        "UpdateDate": "2023-07-01T00:00:00",
        "VersionNumber": "129.00",
        "IndexationDate": "2023-06-26T00:00:00"
    },
    "Sort": null
},
"Data": [
    {
        "companyName": "LE PRINT",
        "bvdIdNumber": "FR834745630",
        "addressLineOne": "2 ALLEE DU PETIT MANOIR",
        "postalCode": "14100",
        "city": "ST MARTIN DE LA LIEUE",
        "country": "France"
}
]
```

So, i need to get Data from JSON.

I was reading the first JSON with this :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<BvdCompanyInfoResponse> companyList =  mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<BvdCompanyInfoResponse>>(){});
```

BvdCompanyInfoResponse class:

```
package com.antalis.core.bvd;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BvdCompanyInfoResponse {
    String companyName;
    String bvdIdNumber;
    String addressLineOne;
    String postalCode;
    String city;
    String country;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getBvdIdNumber() {
        return bvdIdNumber;
    }

    public void setBvdIdNumber(String bvdIdNumber) {
        this.bvdIdNumber = bvdIdNumber;
    }

    

    public String getAddressLineOne() {
        return addressLineOne;
    }

    public void setAddressLineOne(String addressLineOne) {
        this.addressLineOne = addressLineOne;
    }
    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    
}
```

How can I get my company info with new API respone please ? Iv've tried many solutions but with no result.

I tried JSONObject, but it didn't take strings, required type is Map :

```
String jsonString = content.toString() ; //assign your JSON String here
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String dataJson = obj.getJSONObject("Data");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
JsonNode dataNode = rootNode.get("Data");

List<BvdCompanyInfoResponse> companyInfoList = mapper.readValue(
    dataNode.toString(),
    new TypeReference<List<BvdCompanyInfoResponse>>() {}
);
```